# Printing a formatted Float list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, floating-point, formatting

I am writing a program that does the following:

1. Takes multiple inputs (floating point) delimited by commas
2. Performs a calculation on all the elements of the list
3. Outputs a list (floating point with two decimal places)

I have written the following program

```
import math

C = 50.0
H = 30.0
Q = []

D = input("Please input the D-Values\n").split(",")
[float(k) for k in D]
#[int(k) for k in D]

print("D = {}".format(D))

for i in D:
    j = (math.sqrt((2*C*float(i))/H))
    Q.append(j) 


print("The answers are")
print(Q)
print(type(Q[0]))
print("Q = {:.2f}".format(Q))
```

I am facing the following error when executing this program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abrar/pythonPrograms/Challange6.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("Q = {:.2f}".format(Q))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I tried to search for the solution to this problem but could not find an answer. The program works fine if {:.2f} is not included i.e. {} is used. However, the output is then very messy looking.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you are trying to format a `list` with the format string `.2f` -  what you want is to format the `float`s inside your list. this is one way to fix that:

```
Q = [1.3, 2.4]
print(', '.join('{:.2f}'.format(f) for f in Q))
# 1.30, 2.40
```

starting from python 3.6 this could also be written as:

```
print(', '.join(f'{q:.2f}' for q in Q))
```

---

alternatively you could create you own class that accepts format strings:

```
class FloatList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return f'[{", ".join(f"{i:{format_spec}}" for i in self)}]'


fl = FloatList(0.1, 0.33, 0.632)
print(f"{fl:.2f}")  # [0.10, 0.33, 0.63]
```

Comment: This works but is an ugly syntax. I wish Python introduced threading over lists in the future (e.g. in IDL one can use `print, Q, format="f0.2"`) to print the fully formatted list `Q`. It would be much cleaner if Python could use `print(f"{Q:.2f}")` to do the same.

Comment: @divenex well you could inherit from a sequence and define a `__format__` medthod. added an example.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting solution. It's quite verbose for general use. But it would be good if Python f-strings worked along these lines for lists.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to format a list but what you want is to format the elements of this list, hence you need to use `*Q` in place of `Q` (the `*` operator "unpacks" the list)

Here's a solution:

```
fmtL = "Q = " + ', '.join(["{:.2f}"]*len(Q))
print(fmtL.format(*Q))
Q = 1.83, 2.58, 3.16
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm